# Two sums from a join in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I know I can make a join like this:

```
SELECT
    name,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(amount)
        FROM
            actual
        WHERE
            actual.group_id = group.id
    ) AS amount_sum
FROM
    group
```

but what if I need two sums from my join? I have thought of something like:

```
SELECT
    name,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(amount) AS amount_sum
            SUM(time) AS time_sum
        FROM
            actual
        WHERE
            actual.group_id = group.id
    )
FROM
    group
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT name, a.amount_sum, a.time_sum
FROM group g LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT group_id, SUM(amount) AS amount_sum, SUM(time) AS time_sum
      FROM actual
      GROUP BY group_id
     ) a
     ON a.group_id = g.id;
```

Note the use of `left join`.  This ensures that all the groups will be in the output, even when there are no rows in `actual`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use two subqueries:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM actual
        WHERE actual.group_id = groupTable.id
       ) AS amount_sum,
       (SELECT SUM(time)
        FROM actual
        WHERE actual.group_id = groupTable.id
       ) AS time_sum
FROM groupTable
```

Alternatively, join the two tables, then group over the result, which computes the sum in each group:

```
SELECT groupTable.name,
       SUM(actual.amount) AS amount_sum,
       SUM(actual.time)   AS time_sum
FROM groupTable
LEFT JOIN actual ON groupTable.id = actual.group_id
GROUP BY groupTable.id
```